# How to update a nested list of objects using automapper

Tags: c#, dns, automapper

**The problem**

I want to update the nested list of Cabins when I am updating the Ameneties, however at the moment if there are any Cabins coming into the current controller they are simly added to the existing list each with a new ID.

The only method I can think of right now is to ignore the IList in the mapper from resource to object and update cabins in a separate API call.

That does sound like an extra performance load so I am wondering maybe I am missing something and you can do this from the ameneties controller with correct automapper tweak.

Has anyone come across a similar situation? Would really appreciate some help, thank you.

**Model**

```
public class Amenety
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Cabin> Cabins { get; set; }
}

public class Cabin
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public Amenety Amenety { get; set; }
    public int? AmenetyId { get; set; }
}
```

**Resources**

```
public class AmenetyResource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<CabinResource> Cabins { get; set; }
}

public class CabinResource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public int AmenetyId { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPut()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody] AmenetyResource dto)
    {
        var entity = await _repository.GetEntityWhere(i => i.Id == dto.Id);

        if (entity == null)
            return NotFound();

        _mapper.Map(dto, entity);

        await _unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();

        var resource = _mapper.Map<Amenety, AmenetyResource>(entity);


        return Ok(resource);
    }
```

**Mapping**

```
 //to resource
 CreateMap<Amenety, AmenetyResource>();
 CreateMap<Cabin, CabinResource>();

 //from resource
 CreateMap<CabinResource, Cabin>().ForMember(t=>t.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());
 CreateMap<AmenetyResource, Amenety>().ForMember(t => t.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Answer (score 0):

So, after 10 min of sleep and a double shot of coffee it became obvious that I need to include the Cabins in my call to the ameneties inside the contoller in order to work with the list.

```
var entity = await _repository.GetEntityInclude(i => i.Id == dto.Id, c => c.Cabins);
```

So the controller changed to this and it works fine now but you must make sure to provide a full new list of cabins that you want to be there now because during update all the old ones will be erased.